# Splitting READ and WRITE traffic using Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have an API which is deployed on GCP (GKE+External LB) and AWS (EKS + ELB). The DNS resolution is via Route 53.

Can Route 53 split the incoming traffic in way where are READ operations (GET) go to GCP and all writes (PUT/POST etc) goes to AWS.

Basically something like :

**read.domain.com**  going to an external ipv4 address on gcp

**write.domain.com** going to AWS ELB

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up **read.domain.com** to resolve to GCP IPs by just setting up A-records for that. You can use Alias records for **write.domain.com** to point to your ELB.

What you **can't** do is DNS routing based on the HTTPS method (`PUT/POST/GET/...`), that's another layer of the network stack, DNS has no concept of that.
DNS basically does Layer 3 resolution (IP-Addresses) and HTTP is a Layer 5 protocol.

Comment: Thanks @Maurice. I understand your point around DNS routing based on the HTTPS method (PUT/POST/GET/...) is not possible at Layer 3 routing. I will try creating the two A records and do some test as per your response. Also can i throw Weighted Routing for "read.domain.com" in the mix as well, for example the read traffic also gets split into GCP and AWS

Comment: Exactly, that would be possible. Depending on your setup in GCP, you might want to use a CNAME record for the read traffic as well, if you've got a DNS name in GCP. Relying on static IPs should be avoided ;-)

Comment: @indche if this helped, feel free to mark this answer as accepted so other users know this is solved and future readers understand this is something this helped you :-)

Comment: will upvote it when i have enough reputation. As you can see i have just begun. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @indche It's not about the upvote, but [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) - you can do that with any reputation. This is the way anybody that asks a question can show which answer was most suitable for their use case.